# Get city name from latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I was actually making use of 
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?json&ll=13.02761,77.59317 to get the city name.

It was all working till last week.

But now when I try this URL it gives me:

{
  "Status": {
    "code": 610,
    "request": "geocode"
  }
}

Where I am not able to get the city name.

This was working like a charm till some days back.

What I understand by 610 code is:
 G_GEO_BAD_KEY:The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given.

I am not able to understand what went wrong? Initially I wasn't passing any key.

Can somebody please help me out with this as my app is already published in the market and now I am facing this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Sunaina

Answer (score 2):

try this. i've never heard of ll

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=13.02761,77.59317&sensor=true
```

Comment: Thanks I have already tried this. The problem I am facing is to parse it. As I am working for Blackberry.